# Automount'ed Samba Shares accessible via Command Line but hidden in Finder?

Tags: finder, macos, smb, automount

I have 4 samba shares on a Synology DiskStation that I successsfully automount on my 10.9 / Mavericks based system under /Shares/ and when I open the command line I can go there just fine and list the files and directories just fine, however when trying to navigate to /Shares via the Mac OS X finder, the directory just seems entirely empty:

[image: Screenshot]

My /etc/auto_master looks like this:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/Shares         auto_smb    -nosuid
```

... my /etc/auto_smb like this:

```
home -fstype=smbfs,rw,soft ://joerg:myPassword@nasHostname/home
Downloads -fstype=smbfs,rw,soft ://joerg:myPassword@nasHostname/Downloads
Music -fstype=smbfs,rw,soft ://joerg:myPassword@nasHostname/Music
Videos -fstype=smbfs,rw,soft ://joerg:myPassword@nasHostname/Videos
```

What am I missing here? Why aren't the shares displayed in Finder?

Comment: What happens if you type "Shift-Cmd-G" in Finder and enter `/Shares/Music` directly?

Comment: @patrix: tried that and forgot to mention above - it does open the folder and displays/lists the content perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the 'hidefromfinder' option in your auto_master setup file has something to do with it?

```
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,**hidefromfinder**,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,**hidefromfinder**
```

From the auto_master(5) man page:

> The
>        hidefromfinder option is used on maps that shouldn't show up as folders in the Finder; it causes the UF_HIDDEN
>        flag to be set on the root directory of the map.

Comment: It is not specified for the /Shares one(s).. so that shouldn't affect them (and these lines are Maverick default ones, so I wouldn't want to touch them).